# generate dynamic variable name in for loop php

Tags: php

I am trying to generate variable name dynamically in php for loop.
I want call a function within for loop and want to pass iterated values.
What I tried is:

```
for ($i=1, $j=1; $i<=16 ; $i++, $j++) {
    $a='arrtreelevel_1';
    $b='0';
    $newname = $a.$j.$b;
    echo $newname,"<br>";
    echo $arrtreelevel_1[0];
    $arrtreelevel_2.$i = profiledetails($newname);
}
```

My problem is `'$newname'` variable printing `$arrtreelevel_1[0]` as a text not taking the value, and `$arrtreelevel_11[0]` returns the actual value.
I tried with echo `${'arrtreelevel_1$i'}` also which printing nothing. Assist me with any solution please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes ${"arrtreelevel_2$i"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes

```
${"arrtreelevel_2$i"}=profiledetails($newname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$$` to make runtime php variable. Replace this line

```
$arrtreelevel_2.$i = profiledetails($newname);
```

To

```
$tempvar = $arrtreelevel_2.$i;
$$tempvar = profiledetails($newname);
```

Comment: I am getting values for $arrtreelevel_2.$i properly as arrtreelevel_21,arrtreelevel_22 and son on.But $newname is printing  $arrtreelevel_21 but actual  $arrtreelevel_21value is 61 which i wanted.not the name of concatinated variable but the value of it

Comment: @Webbie :  `$tempvar` will give you name `$arrtreelevel_21` and `$$arrtreelevel_21` using `$$` will give you value of `$arrtreelevel_21`