# How can I refactor this variables assignment in foreach loop code?

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement, refactoring, variable-assignment

The code is:

```
foreach($page->items as $item) {
  switch ($item->var) {
    case 'var1': $var1 = $item; break;
    case 'var2': $var2 = $item; break;
    case 'var3': $var3 = $item; break;
    // ...
    case 'varN': $varN = $item; break;
    default: // do nothing
  }
}
```

I would like to make each item var to be assigned to a "named variable" e.g. `$var1` in case of `var1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($page->items as $item) {
  ${$item->var} = $item;
}
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969241/generate-dynamic-variable-name-in-for-loop-php).